# merging some meshes into one

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, mesh, gameobject

I have three parts of an 3D object which I want to merge into one object with one mesh. Two of them are .blend files which are imported from blender and the other one is being structured dynamically. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an empty game object and name it what ever you want and make it parent to your meshes and if you want to move all of your meshes at once you should move the empty game object.

Comment: But this way all of them will be separate objects with one parent, no?

Comment: yes but if you move the parent all of your meshes will move with the parent